# Using controller class's method in other class

Tags: symfony

I want to use renderView()
in other class than Controller.

```
class RegistrationFormHandler extends BaseRegistrationFormHandler  
{

    protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user, $confirmation)
    {
            $messaggio = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ...
        ->setBody($this->renderView('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:firstemailtocustomer.txt.twig',array('user' => $user)));
```

it shows

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler::renderView() in
```

but if you try same method in controller class.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

public function mainAction(){
    $messaggio = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ...
        ->setBody($this->renderView('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:firstemailtocustomer.txt.twig',array('user' => $user)));
```

it works well.

I think I should get instance of controller class.

How can I solove this?

---

Thanks to tim's answer.

I add this to services.xml

```
    <service id="acme.default.controller" class="Acme\MemberBundle\Controller\DefaultController" public="false">
        <argument>acme.controller.default.class</argument>
     </service>
```

and   use like this

```
->setBody($this->forward('acme.controller.default.class')->renderView('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:firstemailtocustomer.txt.twig',array('user' => $user)));
```

but it says,

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler::forward() in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Controller you can [use as a Service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/service.html).

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    # ...
    acme.controller.default.class: Acme\HelloBundle\Controller\UserController

services:
    acme.hello.controller:
        class:     "%acme.controller.default.class%"
```

And then call:

```
$this->forward('acme.hello.controller:mainAction');
```

from `RegistrationFormHandler`.

Comment: THanks Tim,but in my UserBundle requires services.xml.

Comment: I added the information to the article.please help me if you have time/

Comment: I think you should only call `renderView()` from inside a Controller - you must have a Controller somewhere that loads the form validation class. The validation class should only be doing validation, and return a `boolean` to the controller, where you can then render the view.

Comment: I am calling forward in another class(RegistrationFormHandler). Do you think my xml syntax is correct? I am not sure where error exists in xml or php script.

Comment: ah,I understand it's PHP error,but I am not sure my xml symtax is correct and injection is collectlly setup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39551/discussion-between-whitebear-and-tim)

Comment: Thanks tim I read the documents and think that my quesion way is not good. I made another article for this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465671/what-the-templating-service-id

Comment: Thanks to you. I came closer to the core of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
$this->renderView();
```

in a controller, you are using a shortcut for

```
$this->container->get('templating')->renderView();
```

So if you just inject symfony's templating serice in another class you can use renderView from there.

In more detail right in the symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:firstemailtocustomer.txt.twig',array('user' => $user))->getContent();
```