# What the templating service ID?

Tags: symfony

I want to pass the templating EngineInterface  to constructor.

Since ,I want to use renderView() from the class which is not controller class.

```
public function __construct(FormInterface $form, Request $request, UserManagerInterface $userManager, MailerInterface $mailer,TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator,GroupManagerInterface $groupManager,EngineInterface $templating)
{

    parent::__construct($form, $request, $userManager, $mailer,$tokenGenerator);
    $this->groupManager = $groupManager;  
    $this->templating = $templating;
}
```

my current service.xml is this

```
    <service id="acme_user.registration.form.handler" class="Acme\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler" scope="request" public="false">  
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.registration.form" />  
        <argument type="service" id="request" />  
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />  
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.mailer" />
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.util.token_generator" />
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.group_manager" />  
        <argument type="service" id="****" />  <!-- what is templating service iD?  
    </service>
```

What is the templating service ID?

and generally speaking,how can I find the service id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for :

```
<argument type="service" id="templating"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the service id via the console:

```
php app/console container:debug
```

The service you are looking for is called 'templating'.

Comment: The service you search is 'templating'. $this->container->get('templating');

Comment: it is great and useful.